# Calling dll from a Win32 Console Application [C]

Tags: c, dll

Hi everyone and thank you for your time. This was created in Visual Studio 2012,and I'm using the standard Windows Libraries.

I am attempting to call a DLL function explicitly and I believe the code I've written is correct; however, I am receiving an error. I'm not sure if it's an error in something that I've written in the small C console application or from the DLL which I do not have access to the internal workings of.

```
//global area

HINSTANCE _createInstance;
typedef UINT (CALLBACK* LPFNDLLFUNCLOOKUP)(AccuInput*, AccuOut*);
LPFNDLLFUNCLOOKUP lpfnDllFuncCASSLookup;
typedef UINT (CALLBACK* LPFNDLLFUNCINIT)(BSTR);
LPFNDLLFUNCINIT lpfnDllFuncInit;
typedef UINT (CALLBACK* LPFNDLLFUNCCLOSE)(); 
LPFNDLLFUNCCLOSE lpfnDllFuncClose;
HMODULE unmanagedLib;
```

Here is my main function:

```
int main() {

// Load Library
BSTR configFile;
unmanagedLib = LoadLibraryA((LPCSTR) "AccuAddressUnMgd.dll");
// Initialize AccuAddress COM dll
lpfnDllFuncInit = (LPFNDLLFUNCINIT)GetProcAddress(unmanagedLib, (LPCSTR)"Init");
// This function will lookup the address
lpfnDllFuncCASSLookup = (LPFNDLLFUNCLOOKUP)GetProcAddress(unmanagedLib, (LPCSTR)"AccuCassLookup");
// This function will call AccuAddress COM DLL Close function
lpfnDllFuncClose = (LPFNDLLFUNCCLOSE)GetProcAddress(unmanagedLib, (LPCSTR)"Close");
// Append “config.acu” file path.
configFile = SysAllocString(L"C:\PathTo\Config.acu");
printf("ConfigPath created");
lpfnDllFuncInit(configFile);
printf("ConfigFile consumed");
SysFreeString(configFile);
return 0;
}
```

This is the error that I receive:

```
Unhandled exception at at 0x75D4C54F in RDISample1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x001AFAC0.
```

The error occurs at:

```
lpfnDllFuncInit(configFile);
```

So, I guess my question is two parts. Based off the code can I say for a fact that the error is in the DLL function?

Second question, when calling *GetProcAddress* what would be the point (if any) for encapsulating the string in *LPCSTR* like a function versus typecasting?
ie

```
lpfnDllFuncClose = (LPFNDLLFUNCCLOSE)GetProcAddress(unmanagedLib, LPCSTR("Close"));
```

Thanks again for the help. I've been doing a fair amount of research yet DLLs still have been puzzled.

Comment: That looks like a COM exception, and you don't access COM functionality via LoadLibrary or GetProcAddress. What does the documentation for the DLL say?

Comment: Might want to use ``\\`` in your paths instead of ``\``.  May not be contributing to the error, but it probably isn't helping any.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Hey, so I did as you advised and my program now runs through to my return statement! Butttt I'm getting a new error message after the return statement: Error message:  Unhandled exception at 0x00000001 in RDISample1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000001.

Comment: Was the BSTR you're passing in freed by the callee?  It's a likely scenario in COM.  (i.e.  Remove the `SysFreeString` line and see if it works)

Comment: @KenWhite Hey, thanks for the assist. The documentation says to call GetProcAddress like this: lpfnDllFuncClose = (LPFNDLLFUNCCLOSE)GetProcAddress(unmanagedLib, LPCSTR("Close")); My compiler says it's not a function though...

Comment: @Tibrogargan It doesn't look like it. Same error message when I remove the SysFreeString. I appreciate you.

Comment: Your code is very poorly written. You're doing absolutely no error checking; 
you're just assuming that everything is working. Stop doing that, because you can't just pretend that everything works. Every single API call should be checked to make sure it succeeded before you move on. Let  me repeat that: **Every single API call should be checked to make sure it succeeded**. When you use `lpfnDllFuncClose = GetProcAddress()`, your next line of code should be checking to see if `lpfnDllFuncClose` is `NULL` before you do anything else with that pointer.

Comment: Hey @KenWhite I appreciate the advice. I removed the error checks to make the code look more like the DLL documentation when I sent them an e-mail this afternoon. Unfortunately, they are slow and I'm trying my luck here. Here's a link to the documentation. I am using the "Calling the AccuZIPToolkit from C/C++" in the doc found here: https://www.accuzip.com/files/AccuZIPToolkit.pdf. I had to change up their code sample slightly to allow it to compile.

Comment: What @KenWhite says is correct, but it's compounded by whatever library you're calling being junk code.  It crashes because it couldn't open a file that doesn't exist - which means it's not checking error conditions either.  The symptom you're describing is often caused by stack corruption ... and since all you do after the library call is free some memory .. it's a fair bet that's what's going on.  (I'd bet the library is crashing when it's exiting).

Comment: Data *Quality* Toolkit.  lol

Comment: I quote: "Note: You should call Cass.Init() and Cass.Close() only once in a session and not for each record".  Try doing that (i.e.  Add the `Close` call).

Comment: @Tibrogargan I know right lol. Added the close call and unfortunately no change, but at least we got it to run the full length of the program. I'll do some more testing tonight to see if any of the functionality of the DLL actually works. I'm guessing not, but it looks like it's the most I can do until their dev team gets back to me. Appreciate all the help guys. If you add an answer I'll accept it as the answer if I can do that with a newbie account. It technically fixed the error I was getting.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Update: the second error I was receiving was caused by calling the library, not doing anything, and then free memory. Once I updated my code to call the library, doing something, and then free memory, error resolved and so far functioning correctly. Thanks again

Comment: Glad you got it working ... that library you're using is a piece of work.  lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial error is caused by the library you're using failing to correctly handle a file that doesn't exist.

The path you gave contains single slashes `\`, which are treated as escape characters, not path separators.  Path separators must be escaped, i.e. `\\` to be treated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point casting a string literal to LPCSTR.

As for the _com_error that is definitely coming from the DLL. I would suggest wrapping that in a:

```
try
{
  ...
} catch(_com_error const & e)
{
  wprintf(L"Caught a com error: %s\r\n", e.ErrorMessage());
}
```

And then you might be able to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Hey, Visual Studio is not liking me adding the try-catch statement. Specifically the "_com_error" and "const" verbage. So looks like I'll have to do a little research to figure that out. In the meantime, changing \ to \\ seems to fix the immediate problem. Now my program breaks after the return message? Error Message: Unhandled exception at 0x00000001 in RDISample1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000001.